# UWP, ContentControl DataTemplate creates multiple instances of the child control

Tags: xaml, uwp

Here is the context:

I have a list view with a list of files, which can be different type.

I want to display different content when a different type of file is selected.

```xml
        <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                        DataContext="{x:Bind SelectedFile, Mode=OneWay}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" >
            <ContentControl.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="GenericFileTemplate">
                    <mytemplates:GenericFileTemplate SelectedFilter="{Binding ElementName=Host, Path=SelectedFile}" />
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="PhotoFileTemplate">
                    <mytemplates:PhotoFileTemplate SelectedFilter="{Binding ElementName=Host, Path=SelectedFile}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="VideoFileTemplate">
                    <mytemplates:VideoFileTemplate SelectedFilter="{Binding ElementName=Host, Path=SelectedFile}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
```

`Host` is basically just the page itself, which has a dependency property of `SelectedFile`.

I have tried different ways to explicitly trigger the ContentControl update, including

1. Directly find resource in the code behind, such as

```cs
ContentContainer.ContentTemplate = FindTemplate(SelectedFile);
```

2. Using a TemplateSelector, but I have to recreate the ContentTemplateSelector each time a different file is selected

```cs
ContentContainer.ContentTemplateSelector = new FileTemplateSelector();
```

Both cases work.
However, one thing I notice, if I switch file type back and forth from different types. Multiple child control will be created. For example, the sequence:

1. select a generic file first,
2. the generic file template is selected,
3. the generic child control is created;
4. select a photo file
5. the photo file template is selected
6. the generic child control still respond, because the host's `SelectedFile` is changed, but I can ignore it
7. the photo child control is created
8. select a different generic file now
9. the generic file template is selected.
10. the first generic file child control responds (sure, I can accept it)
11. the photo child control responds
12. now a new generic file child control is created (**this seems to be wrong**)

so if I keep switching, the correct datatemplate is selected and assigned to my ContentControl, and then a new child control is created...

Is there a way I can make it to reuse the DataTemplate and its children if it's already loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, no there is no way you can force the ContentControl to reuse the old DataTemplate, especially if you keep swapping out templates or templateselectors yourself instead of changing the content. This is partially because ContentControl can't know how many templates there are, so if it were to cache it, you could end up with a lot of memory consumption.

Even if you cache the datatemplate itsself, you can not cache the rendered child control because of how ContentControl uses the DataTemplate. Other controls such as ItemsRepeater however cache the actual rendered children (also called "container").

Comment: hmm, it makes sense. unfortunately caching the datatemplate in the template selector still doesn't work, it still creates a new child control. I guess the reason is, I am just caching the template, not the rendered visual, so returning a "cached" datatemplate will still result in a new child control in the rendering.

Comment: Yes unfortunately, you can't cache the rendered child control, only the datatemplate because of the way how ContentControl works. Unless you rely on ContentControl, there is not much you can do I think. I'll update my answer to point that out too.

Comment: yup, I ended up using different approach to avoid this issue, I guess it is what it is

Comment: Yeah I wish there was a better solution to this, maybe with WinUI 3, there will be efforts to allow a caching mechanism here.